# What is the meaning of MoveBase::distance?

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, posestamped

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am sorry for my poor English.

I am a beginner at ROS and ROS navigation stack. I would like to know what `double MoveBase::distance(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& p1, const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& p2)` means , which is a function in move_base.cpp. Does it mean the distance from a present point to a goal point?

In addition, I would also like to know the meaning of `geometry_msgs::PoseStamped`. Is it a self position?

I would appreciate it if you could answer my question.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277246/what-is-the-meaning-of-movebase::distance-?/) by [rostaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/31338/rostaro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2017-12-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I would like to know what `double MoveBase::distance(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& p1, const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& p2)` means , which is a function in move_base.cpp. Does it mean the distance from a present point to a goal point?

According to [the code](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/e538b4f4624c7f757d4868e5200ba8f8904a0d94/move_base/src/move_base.cpp#L782-L785), that method calculates the Euclidian distance between `p1` and `p2`. So not necessarily a goal.

> In addition, I would also like to know the meaning of `geometry_msgs::PoseStamped`. Is it a self position?

`p1` and `p2` could be any point.

[geometry_msgs/PoseStamped](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseStamped.html) is a message in the `geometry_msgs` pkg, and those can be used to represent arbitrary poses in a Cartesian coord system, relative to some origin.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rostaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/31338/rostaro/) on 2017-12-04**:
Thank you for answering my question.

Thanks for your clear explanation, I understood that the function is for calculating the Euclidian distance between p1 and p2 ,which are arbitrary points.

Please excuse any mistakes I have made in this letter.
Thank you so much for your lucid instructions.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-04**:
No need to apologise for anything. We're all hear to ask questions and get answers.

**Comment by [rostaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/31338/rostaro/) on 2017-12-04**:
I greatly appreciate your kindness.